# Detecting if a CAPTCHA is needed

Tags: php, mysql, security, captcha

I wish to ask if the code written below has any holes (probably it will be useful for someone else). This code checks, by IP and by `userid`, if more than 5 attempts within the last 5 minutes were made to login. Every attempt to log in is stored in the `history` table (MySQL).

The `history` table is needed only for the purpose of CAPTCHA displaying. ENGINE=InnoDB is chosen for history table.

No indexes were put on `Time` or `userid` or `remote_addr`.

Any suggestions about optimization?

```
$query1="SELECT id FROM history 
    WHERE (Time>date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)) 
        AND remote_addr='" . ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "' limit 6"; 
//limit 6 is for performance, 6+ means 6, we only care if it less than 5
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
//so we know mysql_num_rows($result1)


$query2="SELECT id FROM history 
    WHERE (Time>date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)) 
        AND userid='" . $userid . "' limit 6";
//limit 6 is for performance, 6+ means 6, we only care if it less than 5
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
//so we know mysql_num_rows($result2)



$attempts=0; // we want to set up $attempts=maximum of 
             // (mysql_num_rows($result1), mysql_num_rows($result2))
if($result1) {
    $attempts=mysql_num_rows($result1);
}
if($result2 && $attempts<mysql_num_rows($result2)) {
    $attempts=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}

// if $attempts is more than 5, then CAPTCHA should be displayed, 
// if less then it should not
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1, You should create those indexes. [`Explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) shows whether your queries use indexes or not. If you don't have yet maybe you want a cron job which regularly deletes old records from the table. It improves performance too.

2, As others already mentioned on other questions, if possible, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to avoid possible SQL injections.

3, Choose a meaningful names instead of `$query1` and `$query2` (maybe `$remoteAddrQuery` and `$userIdQuery`). It improves code readability a lot. The same is true for `$result1` and `$result2` (`$remoteAddrResults`, `$userIdResults`).

4, Maybe one query would be enough:

```
$attemptsQuery = "SELECT id FROM history 
    WHERE (Time > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)) 
        AND (remote_addr='" . ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "' 
            OR userid='" . $userid . "')
    LIMIT 6";
```

5, If you don't use the queried records just the count of them use `COUNT(*)`:

```
$attemptsQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as attempts FROM history 
    WHERE (Time > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)) 
    ...
    LIMIT 6";
```

It results a little bit less network traffic between the webserver and the database server and maybe means lower database load.
Of course you have to change `mysql_num_rows` too.

6, Some comments is unnecessary:

```
//so we know mysql_num_rows($result2)
```

7, Instead of commenting create functions whose name say what the comments said. I'd change

```
$attempts=0; // we want to set up $attempts=maximum of 
             // (mysql_num_rows($result1), mysql_num_rows($result2))
if($result1) {
    $attempts=mysql_num_rows($result1);
}
if($result2 && $attempts<mysql_num_rows($result2)) {
    $attempts=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
```

to

```
function getMaxAttempts($result1, $result2) {
    $attempts = 0;
    if ($result1) {
        $attempts = max($attempts, mysql_num_rows($result1));
    }
    if ($result2) {
        $attempts = max($attempts, mysql_num_rows($result2));
    }
    return $attempts;
}
```

It makes the code more readable.

Note that I've removed the first call of `mysql_num_rows($result2)` which maybe improves performance a little bit. (Probably PHP caches it.) A vararg function would be better with a loop but I don't know PHP supports it or nor.

8, If there is an error with the queries or with the database server `mysql_query` will return `FALSE`. Therefore, there will be no captcha displayed at all:

```
if ($result1) {
    $attempts = mysql_num_rows($result1);
}
```

Maybe you want to log and/or show an error message in these cases.

Comment: 7.: I would write it even more different. Reverse the order of the `if` statements and instead of assigning to `$attempts`, just `return` the value immediately.

Comment: I also don't really know much about PHP, but I wouldn't think that PHP caches databse values. If anything, MySQL will cache it.

Comment: @IngoBürk: That seemed fine at first sight but I'm afraid it would give wrong result when `mysql_num_rows($result1) `higher than `mysql_num_rows($result2)`.

Comment: Oh, I just completely didn't see the call to `max`. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where `$userid` comes from.  If it is straight from the request then yes, your code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.  Search the internet for "bobby drop tables" to find out more.